# Wrong output for prime numbers

Tags: c, if-statement, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, c, p;

    printf("enter\n");
    scanf("%d", n);
    c = find(n);
    if (c == 1)
    {
        printf("no. is not prime");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no. is prime");
    }

}

find(int n)
{
    int i = 2, p;

    while (i < n)
    {
        p = n % i;
        printf("value of p%d", p);
        if (p == 0)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

....................................
Above program giving me 'not a prime number' output for all inputs...also the value of p is always zero and this shouldn't be the case...
Please help...badly stuck...

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile this code? I do . . .

Comment: What have you tried to debug your program? Did you try a debugger? Did you try a test `printf` to see if `n` has a value equal to what you actually typed in?

Comment: You need `scanf("%d", &n);` to actually read a value.

Comment: You did not declare the return type of the function find()

Comment: Well, he did not declare the function `find` before using it at all.

Comment: Ah @MOehm true he forgot to declare the function!

Comment: You probably shouldn't use scanf. You should read a line of input and run sscanf on that. unexpected user input tends to produce unfortunate behaviour if you rely on scanf

Comment: @davejagoda No that's the problem...otherwise I would have got right answer...but I got it right now thanks

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for finding out my silly mistake

Answer (score 3):

Your `scanf()` call must take the address of `n`. Furthermore you primality test fails for numbers smaller than 2. It is also better to return non-zero for true, zero otherwise, so that the value can directly be tested with `if`. And you should find a better name than `find`.

Try something like this:

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int is_prime (int n)
{
    int i;

    if (n < 2)
        return FALSE;

    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf ("enter number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    if (is_prime (n)) {
        printf ("number is prime.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("number is not prime.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Various improvements are possible but I wanted to stay as close to your code as possible.

Comment: Thanks for making realize me my silly mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a student exercise so let me start by suggesting that the debugger is your friend. :)

Having said that, you may want to review the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and [leverage Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers#The_first_1000_prime_numbers) for a source of some good test content.

As already suggested, there are loads of potential improvements... I'd modify your "find" function to be more clear as follows:

```
    bool IsPrime(unsigned int n) 
    {
        unsigned int nCounter = 2;

        while (n % nCounter++);

        return (nCounter > n);
    }
```

Prime's can't be negative and since you're asking a "TRUE/FALSE" question, the name and return type should enforce that contract.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. `scanf("%d", n);` should be `scanf("%d", &n);` - you need to pass the *address* of `n` so `scanf` can update it (note that you risk a runtime error,
   since the value of `n` most likely isn't a valid address value);
2. Implicit typing of functions such as `find(int n) {...}` is no longer supported as of the C99 standard, and it was never good practice to begin with.  You should (and for C99 and later, *must*) provide a type specifier along with the function name in both function *declarations* and function *definitions* - `int find( int n ) {...}`;
3. Similar to 2, a function *declaration* must be visible before a function is *called*; the simplest way to accomplish this is to move the function *definition* above the definition for `main`.  If you don't want to do that, then you need to add the declaration `int find(int n);` somewhere before `find` is called.

Note that you can speed up the primality test in a couple of ways.  First, you can skip testing against even factors; if a number is divisible by a multiple of 2, then it's divisible by 2, and you would have already checked for that.  Secondly, you don't need to test all factors up to `n - 1`; you only need to test factors up to the square root of `n`.  You can put that all together like so:

```
if ( n < 2 )
  return 0;  // zero indicates false

if ( n == 2 )
  return 1;  // non-zero indicates true

int result = n % 2;
for ( int i = 3; result && i * i <= n; i += 2 ) // loops as long as result
  result = n % i;                               // is non-zero, only tests
                                                // against odd numbers up to
return result;                                  // sqrt(n)
```